# How can I add legend to scatter density plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, density-plot

How can I add legend to this plot.

[image: scatter plot showing density]

My code is as follows :

```
d1 = densCols(data4$x, data4$y, 
              colramp = colorRampPalette(c("navy blue","yellow","firebrick","firebrick"), 
              space = "Lab"))

ggplot(data4) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y= y, col = d1), size = 0.1) + 
  scale_color_identity() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + 
  labs(x="xaxis", y="yaxis", title="xyz cells") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

theme(legend.position=c(1,1),legend.justification=c(1,1))
```

I tried this and various other things mentioned but don't know why it is not working.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Ok after adding scale_color_identity(guide = "legend"). My graph looks something like this

! [scale_color_identity(guide = "legend")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Juv.png)

Comment: That's not how code formatting works, use the [{}] button instead.

Comment: I don't understand can you give an example please.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other scales, `scale_*_identify()`'s default value of `guide` is `"none"`, which means no legend. So, you need to set `guide = "legend"` manually.

```
ggplot(data4) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y= y, col = d1), size = 0.1) + 
  scale_color_identity(guide = "legend") + 
...
```

The examples in the documentation illustrates this well: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_identity.html

(By the way, I recommend you to try to make your example more simple and reproducible. See [How to make a great R reproducible example? aka MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example-aka-mcve-minimal-complete-and-ver))

Comment: My legend looks weird. It does not have color gradient and number of bins as you would expect. How do I add my plot in the comment section.